# How do you calculate all options of arranging people in cars when you don't want to split up couples?

Tags: combinatorics

I have stumbled upon a weird combinatorics question.

Let's say you have a group of friends who are going on a trip. There are two cars, one provided by a single, let's call it V1, the other provided by a couple, V2. This means you have 4 places in the first car and 3 places in the second car.

Your passengers are 2 couples and 2 singles, which you need to divide over the two cars.

So you have two cars. Vehicle 1, V1, has 4 places. Vehicle 2, V2, has 3 places. You have 2 couples, C1 and C2, and two singles, S1 and S2.

**What are all the possible combinations you could arrange the cars, given you don't want to split up couples?**

Below I have put the problem in a table and provided an example solution.

[Problem statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ix4dX.png)

[Solution 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtlDu.png)

[All solutions (I think)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xO8MV.png)

Comment: and... what have you tried so far except for making table in excel ? You cannot get answer without putting your effort in your post

Comment: I recommend splitting this into cases. You either have both couples in V1 or they are split between the two cars. Distribute the couples first then distribute the singles.

Comment: @NotaSalmonFish I have found all the combinations by brute force I think but I am struggling to generalise them mathematically. For this case, [these are the solutions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xO8MV.png) (I think). For the case with no couples, I think the answer is 6 choose 3, or 20, ways because you have 6 people and you can choose three of them to fill V2. The other car is filled with the remaining people.

Comment: @Vasili That's a good idea, thanks!I'll try to generalise it that way.

Comment: @CarDriver without couples the answer is 7 choose 3. This is because you aren't putting 6 people into 6 spaces but 6 people and 1 empty space into 7 places.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways to do this by cases, but an efficient way is to notice that this is the same as the number of ways to seat two couples and three singletons, using up all the seats.

Now there are only two cases, since there must be an odd number of singletons in the second car. Both cases are easy to count.